# React context custom input validation displays all errors when typing in any input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I'm looking for is to have my custom input validation to show errors input by input, as I type into them (not on submit). What it does now is showing every errors as soon as I type inside any input. I know the reason : because `setErrors()` is in `handleFormChange()`, therefore every errors are set as soon as I type in any input, but I can't find a solution that meets my needs.

What I try to do is put most of the form's logic in the `Form` component, as it is where `FormContext` is defined. I believe doing so will give me more reusability, as the only parts I would need to change to reuse the components are only the `validate` function (to define the input's rules) and the `onSubmit` function, that are located in the parent component (here `App`). No need to touch anything on `Form` or `FormInput` when everything will be set.

I know `react-hook-form` and how to use it but I would like to create my own form / input validation logic. Everything works as needed expect this error display problem.

Here is the `Form` component (including `FormContext`) :

```
export const FormContext = createContext({
    form: {},
    errors: {},
});

export default function Form({
    formInitialValues,
    onSubmit = () => {},
    validate = () => {},
    children
}) {
    const [form, setForm] = useState(formInitialValues);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    
    const handleFormChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target || e;
        
        const updatedForm = {
            ...form,
            [name]: value,
        };
        
        const errors = validate(updatedForm);
        
        setForm(updatedForm);
        setErrors(errors);
    };
    
    return (
        <FormComp>
            <FormContext.Provider value={{
                form,
                errors,
                handleFormChange,
            }}>
                { children }
            </FormContext.Provider>

            <button type="button" onClick={() => onSubmit(form)}>
                Envoyer
            </button>
        </FormComp>
    )
}
```

Here is my `FormInput` component :

```
export default function FormInput({
    label,
    type = 'text',
    name,
    forwardRef,
}) {
    const formContext = useContext(FormContext);
    const { form, errors, handleFormChange } = formContext;
    
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <InputGroup>
            <label>{ label }</label>
            <input
                type={type}
                name={name}
                value={form[name]}
                onChange={handleFormChange}
                ref={forwardRef ? forwardRef : inputRef} />
            { errors && errors[name] && errors[name].length > 0 && <span>{ errors[name] }</span> }
        </InputGroup>
    )
}
```

And here is my `App` component, where I define the `validate` function (that is used in `Form -> handleFormChange()`) :

```
function App() {
    const initialValues = {
        lastName: '',
        firstName: '',
    };
    
    const validate = (form) => {
        let errors = {};

        if (form.lastName === '') {
            errors.lastName = 'Last name is required'
        }
        if (form.firstName === '') {
            errors.firstName = 'This field is required';
        }
        
        return errors;
    };
    
    const onSubmit = (form) => {
        console.log({ form });
    };
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>S'inscrire</h1>
        
        <Form
            formInitialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            validate={validate}
        >
            <FormInput
                label="Nom"
                name="lastName" />
            <FormInput
                label="Prénom"
                name="firstName" />
        </Form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction ? I tried lots of stuff but nothing works (at least nothing that meets my needs). This should be simple but I don't understand why I can't get it right (even though I know where the problem lies). Thank you very much for your help.

**---------- EDIT ----------**

Ok so I found a way to make it happen, but it seems a little bit "too much" (and still not working properly), I'm guessing there should be a more simple way to achieve what I want.

So what I did is setting a new state `errors` in the parent component (`App`) that I use to set the errors in the `validate` function (they are not set in `Form -> handleFormChange()` anymore), that I then pass down as a prop to `Form`. Here are the modified parts :

`App` component :

```
function App() {
    //.... Cut down unnecessary parts ....

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

    const validate = (name, value) => {

        const omit = (key, { [key]: _, ...obj }) => obj
        
        switch (name) {
            case 'lastName':
                if (value === '') {
                    setErrors({
                        ...errors,
                        [name]: 'Last name required',
                    });
                }
                else {
                    let newObj = omit('lastName', errors);
                    setErrors(newObj);
                }
                break;

            case 'firstName':
                if (value === '') {
                    setErrors({
                        ...errors,
                        [name]: 'First name required',
                    });
                }
                else {
                    let newObj = omit('firstName', errors);
                    setErrors(newObj);
                }
                break;
        }

    //.... Same as before ....
}
```

Then here is the new `Form` component (I'm just showing the `handleFormChange` function, everything is the same expect for the fact that I pass down the `errors` prop from `App` to `Form` (used in `handleFormChange() -> validate()`) :

```
const handleFormChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target || e;
        
    const updatedForm = {
        ...form,
        [name]: value,
    };
                
    setForm(updatedForm);
    validate(name, value);
};
```

So as you can see, `validate()` still runs in `Form` but the errors are not set in `Form` anymore (they are set inside `validate()`, in the parent component `App`, in the `switch` statement).

This almost works as I would like : the error messages show input by input, but only one input at the time. What I mean is, if I type in and blank the first input, it displays the error for this input only, but then if I type in the second input while the first error is set, the first error message disappears but the second input error message displays (and even if I don't trigger the second input's error, it still hides the first error message), and vice versa.

What am I doing wrong ? I would greatly appreciate some advice. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the problem and now everything works as expected : as you type in the first input, if an error occurs for that input it displays it. Then if you type in the second input and an error occurs there, it also displays. And when I have no more errors, it hides them input by input.

What I missed was only better defining `values` in the `validate()` `switch` statement. What I mean is, before I only did `if (values === '')`, where I needed to do `if (values.fieldName === '')` to set the errors.

Here is the new `validate` function in the parent component (`App`) (note that I also use the `name` variable everywhere I can to avoid repeating `lastName` and `firstName`) :

```
switch (name) {
            case 'lastName':
                if (values.lastName === '') {
                    setErrors({
                        ...errors,
                        [name]: 'Lastname is required'
                    })
                }
                else  {
                    let newObj = omit(name, errors);
                    setErrors(newObj);
                }
                break;
            case 'firstName':
                if (values.firstName === '') {
                    setErrors({
                        ...errors,
                        [name]: 'Firstname is required'
                    })
                }
                else {
                    let newObj = omit(name, errors);
                    setErrors(newObj);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

And here is the `handleFormChange` function in `Form`, where I needed to do `validate(name, udpatedForm.values)` instead of `validate(name, updatedForm)` (or as I showed before `validate(name, values)`) :

```
const handleFormChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target || e;
        
        const updatedForm = {
            ...form,
            values: {
                [name]: value
            },
        };
        
        validate(name, updatedForm.values);
        setForm(updatedForm);
    };
```

So that was just a silly error on my part... But now everything works great ! I now have my full reusable form / input validation using `React context`, and if I want to reuse the components, I just have to modify the `validate` function in the parent component (as well as `formInitialValues`), and everything is handled within the `Form` component, holding the context. So no need to touch this anytime soon ! Reusability for life (at least until I decide to add some stuff up maybe).

Note that I still set the errors in the parent component (in `validate()`), that I then pass down as props to `Form`. Is anyone as a better suggestion for going about this, please go ahead (I would have liked all the errors to be set in `Form` but eh, that's what I came up with, it works and meets my needs). Thank you very much